# Why string inputs as doubles are outputting this answer

Tags: java, try-catch, try-catch-finally, inputmismatchexception

I'm very new and I'm just curious to know why this code outputs 201.0 when entering 2E2 as the value of the double.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double r = 2E2;
    try{
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        r=-1.0;
    }
    finally{
        r++;
    }
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

output: 201.0

Comment: What do you think 2E2 means?

Comment: Because `2E2` is `200.0`. As there is no exceptions in try block only finally block runs and it increases that to `201.0`

Answer (score 3):

By putting in the E you are saying 2 * 10 ^ 2 power. The additional 1 comes from the finally block which is always executed even if there is an error thrown. If you were to put 2E3 it would print out 2001.0!

Answer (score 0):

2E2 in decimal notation is 200. Your try catch block does not contain any code, so it never reaches the exception block and the finally block increments 2E2 by adding 1 to it. So, the answer is 2E2 + 0X1 = 0x2E3 (201.0), which is the correct. Finally, when you print it, it is displayed in the decimal format as 201.0.